# JS loadResponse doesnt work

Tags: javascript, rest, jsp, calculator

I am building a basic calculator using JavaScript.

```
<script>
    function loadResponse(x){
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById("resultDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;  
            }
        }
        var uri = "http://localhost:8080/REST_service/rest/calculator/";
        switch(x){
            case 1:
                uri += "add/";
                break;

            case 2:
                uri += "subtract/";
                break;

            case 3:
                uri += "multiply/";
                break;

            case 4:
                uri += "divide/";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        uri += document.getElementsByName("num1").value + "/" +
                    document.getElementsByName("num2");
        console.log(uri);
        xmlhttp.open("POST", uri, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
<body>
        Number 1: <input type="text" name="num1" />
        Number 2: <input type="text" name="num2" />
        <input type="button" onclick="loadResponse(1)" value="ADD" />
        <input type="button" onclick="loadResponse(2)" value="SUBTRACT" />
        <input type="button" onclick="loadResponse(3)" value="MULTIPLY" />
        <input type="button" onclick="loadResponse(4)" value="DIVIDE" />

    <div id="resultDiv"></div>
</body>
```

But the console.log doesnt work, so the function is not getting called.

What am I doing wrong? How can I improve this code- calling loadResponse in a better way and also sending the values across to server side?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: You're missing `.value` after `document.getElementsByName("num2")`

Comment: `document.getElementsByName()` returns a collection, not a single element. You need to index it with `[0]` to access the value. Or change to using an ID instead of name, and `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: Yes, this was it. I'm a noob in this, thanks! Can you suggest a cleaner way of doing this, specially to send the values?

Comment: Your way is clean enough, just need to fix the bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
    uri += document.getElementsByName("num1").value + "/" +
                document.getElementsByName("num2");
```

`getElementsByName()` returns a `NodeList`, so you need to index it to access the value. And you didn't use `.value` for the second field. It should be:

```
    uri += document.getElementsByName("num1")[0].value + "/" +
                document.getElementsByName("num2")[0].value;
```